# Flask session drops data when used with redis server side session

Tags: docker, redis, flask-session

Two setups. Two different results.

Setup 1: Flask app running in develop mode, redis running in local container.

Session data persists across the requests.

Setup 2: Flask app running on an AWS EC2 instance in container with redis running in container in a docker-compose environment with an nginx container in the docker compose environment.

Some session data fails to persist between requests.

The exciting thing is that if I store the session on the cookie, the system works as expected and all state is stored in Setup 2.

Unsure about any of the following:

- why certain session items persisting and others are not.
- why this works locally repeatably and not on the EC2 instance.
- What's going wrong and (hopefully) how I fix or debug it.

UPDATE:
Session config for server side session:

```
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = 600
SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
SESSION_REDIS = redis.from_url('redis://redis')
```

which is part of the app configuration.
Other than that, I set up flask-session with

```
from flask_session import Session
app = Flask(__name__)
Session(app)
```

(modulo the boilerplate code used to create the app.) Removing the call to `Session(app)` and the config fixes the session not dropping data. I need to use redis becuase the session cookie isn't big enough to store some of the sessions.

Comment: Can you give some details (code) on how you've implemented sessions is the faulty configuration, vs how you stored that data on the cookie.

Comment: Good point @v25 Hope this highlights enough.

Comment: Yes, although I'm not really sure what could be causing this, how annoying.  Do you happen to have a repo link for your code?